# Arrows only for rangeSelector in HighCharts

Tags: jquery, function, highcharts, customization, arrows

Is it possible to only have the left and right arrows for the rangeSelector when using HighCharts?

[image]

I actually don't want the rangeSelector, just the functionality of the arrows on the scrollbar. I can't find anything within the docs.

Comment: To use scrollbar, you need to use Highstock (highstock.js file).

Answer (score 1):

You should set [`navigator.enabled`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#navigator.enabled) property to false, like this:

```
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {   
    navigator: {
        enabled: false
    },
    ...
});
```

#### [Working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/iluzyanin/mwgL2okw/)

Comment: Thx for sharing. However, I wish to keep the arrows only without scrollbar. I ended up finding another solution which I customized and put together.

Comment: Well, that wasn't obvious from the question. Anyway, glad you found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding another solution which I customized to do what I needed exactly.

JS:

```
$(function () {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        title:{
            text:''
        },
        chart: {
            type: 'area',
            renderTo: 'container'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', 'YTD'],
        },
        yAxis: {
            gridLineColor: '#FFFFFF'
        },

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
        },

        scrollbar: {
            enabled: false
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                pointStart: 2010,
                fillColor: {
                    linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 300],
                    stops: [
                        [0, '#E5EBF7']
                    ]
                }
            }
        },

        series: [{
            color: '#EBEEF5',
            data: [135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
            marker: {
                fillColor: '#71abd1'
            }
        }]
    });
    $(".rangeBtn").click(function() {
        if (!chart) return;
        var extremes = chart.xAxis[0].getExtremes();
        var range = extremes.max - extremes.min;
        var thisBtnIs = $(this).attr('id');
        if(thisBtnIs == "prev") {
            var newMin = extremes.min - range;
            chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(newMin, extremes.min);
        }
        if(thisBtnIs == "next") {
            var newMax = extremes.max + range;
            chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(extremes.max, newMax);
        }
        chart.showResetZoom();
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>

<div id="rangeSelector">
    <button id="prev" class="rangeBtn"><</button>
    <button id="next" class="rangeBtn">></button>
</div>
```

STYLE:

```
#rangeSelector{
    left: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

[**View demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/nf1nmyjg/embedded/result/).